# Data change in firebase is occuring from the second button click, First click does nothing

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When i click the button first time , data is not updated in firebase and from the second click onwards only the data gets updated. 
Flag is set as false as global variable

```
private void incrementDay(){
        db_total = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Total Days");
        db_total.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                try {
                    getTotal =  (long)dataSnapshot.getValue();
                    setTotal=getTotal+1;
                    flag=true;
                }catch( NullPointerException ne){
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
        if(flag){
            db_total.setValue(setTotal);
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),"Days updated",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. Any code that needs the data needs to be *inside* the `onDataChange` that gets called when the data is loaded.

So something like:

```
private void incrementDay(){
    db_total = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Total Days");
    db_total.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            getTotal =  (long)dataSnapshot.getValue();
            setTotal=getTotal+1;
            db_total.setValue(setTotal);
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),"Days updated",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            throw databaseError.toException();
        }
    });
}
```

But note that you're updating the database value based on its current value. If two users do this at almost the exactly same time, only one of their writes will make it into the database. That's why you should always put such updates into a Firebase transaction.

Something like:

```
db_total.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
    @Override
    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData current) {
        long count = current.getValue(Long.class);
        mutableData.setValue(count + 1);
        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                           DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // Transaction completed
        Log.d(TAG, "updating count:" + databaseError);
    }
});
```